# Duplicate declaration of type' at token ';' when trying to declare a SELinux type

Tags: android, build, android-source, selinux

I'm trying to build a ROM for my phone (Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite) with SELinux enforcing. I've booted the phone successfully in permissive mode, however in the enforcing mode the Wi-fi won't work and SystemUI restarts every few minutes, displaying "Phone is starting..." instead of the launcher screen.

I used `audit2allow` to grab SELinux denials from my phone and added the output to the list of SELinux policies. However, when I try to compile the ROM, I get the following error:

```
device/xiaomi/daisy/sepolicy/daisy.te:224:ERROR 'unknown type qemu_hw_mainkeys_prop' at token ';' on line 75538:
allow platform_app qemu_hw_mainkeys_prop:file read;
```

After getting that error, I declared the type in my property.te file:

```
type qemu_hw_mainkeys_prop, property_type;
```

And after trying to compile the ROM again I get this:

```
device/xiaomi/daisy/sepolicy/property.te:3:ERROR 'Duplicate declaration of type' at token ';' on line 75576:
type qemu_hw_mainkeys_prop, property_type;
```

DT: https://github.com/tkchn/android_device_xiaomi_daisy/

Comment: I am facing same error. Can you please let me know ,How you resolved .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Android will append all te files to one file. You need to add a blank line at the end of each te file, otherwise the last line of previous file and first line of current file will be mixed. And also, I prefer that you also add a blank line at the beginning of each te file to avoid format error from other te files.

Comment: Any other possibilities? I do have empty lines at the end and beginning of each file and I am still running into this issue.

Comment: Still, i am also facing same problem.

Comment: @Oserd Brockhoist , i have done same thing what you suggested. Still facing same error.

Comment: @GNK, selinux build problems depends on the log analysis, please share your error logs

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same duplicate declaration error. Here's my device directory structure:

```
device/
  my_company/
    my_device/
      BoardConfig.mk
      my_device.mk
    common/
      sepolicy/
        property.te
      my_system.mk
```

Inside `my_device.mk` I have:

```
$(call inherit-product, device/my_company/common/my_system.mk)
```

At first in `my_system.mk` I had:

```
BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS += device/my_company/common/sepolicy
```

But this produced the error, so I removed the above `BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS` line from `my_system.mk` and put it into `BoardConfig.mk`. The error went away, wish I could explain why exactly but maybe you have the same problem.